# operator= overloading, terminator called recursively

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

I am having an issue with overloading the assignment operator. I am getting a "terminator called recursively" error in the console.

I am relatively new to data structures and I'm having trouble debugging this issue.

Here is the class declaration:

```
class Player
{
public:
    Player(const unsigned int x_, const unsigned int y_, const char i_);
    Player(const Player& p_);
    ~Player();

    unsigned int getX() const;
    unsigned int getY() const;
    char getI() const;

    void updatePosition(int newX, int newY);

    Player& operator=(const Player& p_);
private:
    struct Position{
        unsigned int x;
        unsigned int y;
    };

    Position* pos;

    char i;
};
```

And here is the implementation of the operator= function:

```
Player& Player::operator=(const Player& p_)
{
    delete pos;
    pos = nullptr;

    pos = new Position();
    pos->x = p_.getX();
    pos->y = p_.getY();

    i = p_.getI();

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: There is no good reason for `pos` to be a pointer. It's only complicating things and forcing the need for the copy and assignment operators. No pointer, no problems. Or at least not the one you're currently fighting with.

Comment: Can you add the actual error message?

Comment: best guess -- you're trying to assign a Player to itself: `Player p;` ... `p = p;`  or something equivalent.

Comment: How sure are you that `pos` points to a valid `Position`?

Comment: Warning: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015156/what-is-wrong-with-checking-for-self-assignment-and-what-does-it-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using `Position* pos` is not a good choice.
You always have to initialize it by constructor.

Although you did so, in `Player& operator=(const Player& p_)`,
i think there is trouble with first line and second line.
You already removed `pos` in memory by `delete pos`
but you're trying to set `pos` to `nullptr`.